# Where do I start with creating an app that prefills passwords of listed URLs (or even applications too)

Tags: .net, scripting, textbox, keyboard-events

I've been going from entry level to entry level job but now I've decided to begin putting together a "portfolio" of sorts so that I can get into the development game. 
I am looking to create an app that saves passwords and usernames. I am going to spam the heck out of the random function in the .net "function box" in visual studio 2017 and the substring with some random keyboard-smashing to make up the "libraries of random characters" that I am going to substitute within random index's of of the original password from an arraylist that I am going to store it in to create the semi"random" encryption if you want to call it. And I am familiar with working between SQL server and the Application Form Box interface to store my 'username, password or email'

> > >
> >      but an important feature that I'm not even sure where to get started on is making my app actually interact with an actual web form right when my End User pulls up a website. I want the application to tab to recognize the website, the instant an End User goes to it, on a given browser, (probably just chrome if that's easier) I want my app which is running in the background, to "tab" or go-to the textboxes on the webpage that ask for Username and Password, and actually sign into it. I want to build a program that can literally tab to the area on a webpage that says "username password, "login" and actually paste to the text-boxes the saved ' username and password '. I think I need whatever function it is within the .net framework that can interact with the virtual keyboard and use the keys and somehow scanning the webpage for words that say "username" or "password" or "login" and then work out a set of commands that actually **imitates keyboard input** and follows a chain of commands such as 'tab' (for *selecting* at a given "text-index" of the page, the textbox below or to the right of it) copy/paste, to copy/paste some variable that corresponds with the webpage the person is on (and pull that from my password database). That's it. I just want to put my own text into the textbox of a website for credentials that comes from an external database or local storage on the app. 
> >     I do not know if there is an easier way to do this. I literally did not know where to start, in order to make a .net app run a program that interacts with the browser that is pulling from a url that I have and I want my app to add text into some text-box that it will somehow recognize.

Comment: Please note that SO is neither a code-writing nor tutorial service; this question is far too broad.

Comment: I mean, I just want to know where to get started in creating an app in .net framework that will interact with webbrowser web form (via "virtual keyboard" I assumed). Like is it even possible?